# Finding an item in a set of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data:

```
d = set(("John", "Griffin"), ("Lisa","Kane"), ("Mike", "Doyle"), ...)
```

How do I check this data to see if it contains the first name "Ian" where I have tens of thousands of items in my set?

I guess something like this would work:

```
len((i for i in d if i[0] == "Ian")) > 0
```

but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: `any(a == 'Ian' for a, b in d)`.

Comment: Do you have to keep the data that way? A dict would be much more helpful for the particular problem you're asking.